# onOptionsItemSelected item shows method dont work?

Tags: android, methods, android-viewpager, menuitem

As a topic: 
With the current state of my work, I can show items on settings tab and action bar.
But the methods included don't work like expected. I'm not sure what's the problem.

Can you take a look at the following code to help me understand my errors?

```
public class Automat extends Activity {

    DataBase dataBase;
    ArrayList<Resource> res;
    ViewPager myPager;
    boolean move;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_automat);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();
        move=true;


        dataBase = new DataBase(this);
        dataBase.open();

        res = dataBase.getList();

        ViewPagerAdapter2 adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter2(this, res, dataBase);
        System.out.println("ADAPTER" + adapter);

        myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myPager2);
        //myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter.startUpdate(myPager);
        dataBase.close();

        class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {
                         if (move){              
                             myPager.setCurrentItem(myPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                         }else {}

                     }
                });

                System.out.println("");
           }
        }

        MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();

        myTimer.schedule(myTask, 15000, 15000);             
    }


    /**
        * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
        */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.automat, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            switchPause();

            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);       
    }

    private void switchPause(){
        if(move){
            System.out.println("MOVE = FALSE");
            move=false;
        }else {
            System.out.println("MOVE = true");
            move=true;
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In method `onOptionsItemSelected` use code like following

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```